# linearlayout erasing the important part of the text on a small screen

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

What I would like to achieve is to make the area 1 smaller automatically, so it will keep the text on 2 lines, but won't affect the area 2 of the layout. It is essential for me to display all of the information in the area 2.

Here is the code of my layout:

```
<!-- Content of the header -->
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <!-- More details button -->
    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_more"
            android:onClick="expandView"
            android:id="@+id/card_button_more_details" />

    <!-- Edit nickname button -->
    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:onClick="editNickname"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_edit"
            android:id="@+id/card_button_edit_nickname"/>

    <!-- Nickname or number of the card -->
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/card_value_nickname_or_number"
            android:layout_margin="8dp" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <!-- Current balance -->
    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/frameLayoutBalanceClosed"
            android:background="@drawable/balance_warning">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/card_value_balance"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:singleLine="true" android:gravity="center_vertical" 
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to change your linear layout to relative layout. set the first three view (2 image view and the text view) alighted to the left, while the last text view will be alighted to right with fixed size. that should fix your issue.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Fixed size will fix the issue in the linear layout as well, but the problem is that size has to be dynamic.

Comment: yeah but you said that the last text box is of much more importance so the size of the central text view will change accordingly to screen size while the last text view will stay fixed to it's size for always displaying it's content.

Comment: True, I guess you are right. I'll do it as a workaround, but hopefully we'll find a more appropriate solution. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: you welcome, I don't think you will find a solution that uses linear layout as a base layout for you raw.